# How to update a list item of list in react-redux by using ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have to use ES6 feature to update a single item from list in react-redux project.
My reducer is like this:-

```
var initialState={
     data: [],
     updatedData={}
}
function labResultReducer(state =initialState, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case "GET_DATA:
       return Object.assign({}, state, {
       data: action.data
       });
  case "UPDATE_DATA":
        {(//......how to update the record
      });
  default:
  return state
}
```

Here updatedData is the updated object returning from action.

> In Switch case "UPDATE_DATA"
>    how can I assign the new object to the list? I don't want to mutate
>   the state and I am using the ES6 in our project.Please assist me

.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator to updated nested state data based on action payload:

```
  case "UPDATE_DATA":
        return {...state, 
             updateData: {
                ...state.updateData,
                [action.updatedDataId]: action.updatedData
             }
        }
```